# Не работает загрузка doc файла в safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование

Загрузка не работает только в safari - http://bravegk-russia.ru/?page_id=2

https://studfile.net/preview/5252235/#5252235, на этом сайте документ открывается в другой вкладке, при нажатии "скачать".

Сайт на wp, скачать нужно вложение.

Как сделать так, чтобы doc файл с сайта открывался в safari при скачивании?

Comment: Никак — документы Microsoft Word нельзя просмотреть в Safari. (PDF, к примеру, можно).

Comment: @IgorR. Спасибо, а каким образом реализовано на втором сайте?

Comment: Если Вы о тексте, который на странице, то, вероятно, он отображается как HTML, браузер тут не играет роли. «на этом сайте документ открывается в другой вкладке, при нажатии "скачать".» — это не так, загружается как документ Word.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно попробовать такой способ:

```
<a href="images/name.jpg" download="newname.jpg">Скачать файл</a>
```

Если нужного результата не дало, тогда нужно в JavaScript по событию перенаправить на полный или абсолютный путь к файлу. Для этого описана функция:

```
function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
```

Вы пробовали использовать `iframe`?

Источники:
1. https://javascript.ru/forum/events/48870-kak-skachat-fajjl-cherez-js.html